# Displaying A List to a Certain Decimal - Python 3.x

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing

I'm having trouble displaying my list in a money format ($0000.00)

```
priceList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for i in range (10):
    priceList[i] = random.uniform(1,1000)
print (priceList)
```

If I try

```
print ('%.02d' %(priceList))
```

Python returns

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the printing inside your `for` loop:

```
priceList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(10):
    priceList[i] = random.uniform(1,1000)
    print("${:07.02f}".format(priceList[i]))
```

In `07.02f`, `07` says to make sure that the string is at least 7 characters long.  The `0` is there because if the string is less than 7 characters, that is the character to be used to make it 7 characters.  `02` before the `f` means that there should be at least two characters after the decimal point.  The `0` is there so that if there are fewer than two characters, it will be used to fill it in.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot print a list this way, you need to print each list item. A list comprehension works well here:

```
[print('%.02f' % i) for i in priceList]
```

Comment: @idjaw true, wasn't thinking that much about the actual code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to do that operation over a list. You need to do it on each element in your list. Try this:

Also, I think you want to use %.02f and not %.02d

```
print(' '.join('%.02f' % (x) for x in priceList))
```

Output:

```
728.08 289.73 117.96 29.70 562.40 255.97 213.55 235.08 436.10 654.54
```

If you want it just as a list, you can simply do this only:

```
print(['%.02f' % x for x in priceList])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using proper Python 3 format strings. You can do something like this:

```
import random
priceList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range (10):
    priceList[i] = random.uniform(1,1000)

moneyList = list(map(lambda x: "${:07.02f}".format(x), priceList))
print(moneyList)  # => output:
"""
['$294.90', '$121.71', '$590.29', '$45.52', '$319.40', '$189.03', '$594.63', '$135.24', '$645.56', '$954.57']
"""
```